# Need help in understanding how transform-origin works in CSS

Tags: html, css

I went through [CSS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-origin-property), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)/[Opera](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css3-transitions-and-2d-transforms/#transforms) articles on transform-origin, , but couldn't understand exactly how transform-origin works.

I have setup a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgr0hmto/48/). The div with class "*test*" is a "*50px*" wide square. There is a button clicking on which rotates the *div* *30 degrees*. Sample HTML is as below

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='test'></div>
</div>
<button class='button'>
    Rotate
</button>
```

Sample CSS is as below

```
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin: 70px 80px;
}
```

If I set transform origin to the edges of the square like (0,0)/(50px,0)/(0,50px)/(50px, 50px) or any point on the circumference/area inside the square I can slightly visualize how the transform origin is working.
But if I set the property to a point outside the bounds of the square, I couldn't visualize or understand where exactly the div is shifted to.

In MDN/Opera article, there is a phrase as below,

> From MDN
>
> "This property is applied by first translating the element by the
> negated value of the property, then applying the element's transform,
> then translating by the property value.)"
>
> From Opera
>
> Technically the transform origin is applied by calculating the
> negation of the transform-origin value (-3em on the X axis, and the
> top of the element in the example above), translating the element to
> this value, then applying the transform that is specified in the
> transform property, then translating the element by the actual value
> of the transform-origin.

It adds to further confusion if I try to follow the above steps and trace where exactly the div will be placed in the co-ordinate system.

Any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the values section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin - it pretty much explains it - your above origin is 70px on the x axis from the left edge of your original shape and 80px from the top edge of your original shape

Comment: Also a good article: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very good pen by [Dan Wilson](https://codepen.io/danwilson/) that will give you a visual explanation of how [Transform Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) works:

https://codepen.io/danwilson/full/EXqEZM

```js
var display = document.getElementById('transform-origin');
var origin = document.querySelector('.origin');
var style = document.documentElement.style;

var autopilot;
autopilot = setTimeout(() => {
  change();
  autopilot = setInterval(change, 3000)
}, 1500);

function change(ex, ey) {
  var x = ex || (Math.random());
  var y = ey || (Math.random());
  style.setProperty('--x', x);
  style.setProperty('--y', y);
  display.textContent = Math.round(x * 100) + '% ' + Math.round(y * 100) + '%';
}

document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', onPress);
document.documentElement.addEventListener('touchend', onPress);
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var box = origin.getBoundingClientRect();
var side = box.right - box.left;

function onPress(e) {
  clearTimeout(autopilot);
  clearInterval(autopilot);
  
  var x = e.clientX || e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
  var y = e.clientY || e.changedTouches[0].clientY;
  
  if (window.innerWidth !== width || window.innerHeight !== height) {
    box = origin.getBoundingClientRect();
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
    side = box.right - box.left;
  }
  
  var ex = (x - box.left) / side;
  var ey = (y - box.top) / side;
  
  change(ex,ey);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --x: .5;
  --y: .5;
  --side: 30vmin;
  --duration: 1500ms;
  --easing: ease-in-out;
}

.shape {
  animation: rotate 1000ms infinite linear;
  transition: transform-origin var(--duration) var(--easing);
  transform-origin: calc(var(--x) * 100%) calc(var(--y) * 100%);
  
  
  width: var(--side);
  height: var(--side);
  background: 
    linear-gradient(315deg, hsl(248, 40%,50%) 10%, transparent 10%, transparent), 
    linear-gradient(225deg, hsl(348, 40%,50%) 10%, transparent 10%, transparent), 
    linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(48, 40%,50%) 10%, transparent 10%, transparent), 
    linear-gradient(45deg, hsl(168, 40%,50%) 10%, hsl(168, 70%,50%) 10%, hsl(168, 70%,50%));
  position: relative;
  will-change: transform, transform-origin;
}
.point {
  --point: 1vmin;
  background: black;
  width: var(--point);
  height: var(--point);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--point) * -.5);
  left: calc(var(--point) * -.5);
  transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * var(--side)), calc(var(--y) * var(--side)));
  transition: transform var(--duration) var(--easing);
  will-change: transform;
  opacity: .6;
}
.origin {
  width: var(--side);
  height: var(--side);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px dashed hsl(233, 70%, 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(315deg, hsla(248, 40%,50%, .2) 10%, transparent 10%, transparent), 
    linear-gradient(225deg, hsla(348, 40%,50%, .2) 10%, transparent 10%, transparent), 
    linear-gradient(135deg, hsla(48, 40%,50%, .2) 10%, transparent 10%, transparent), 
    linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(168, 40%,50%, .2) 10%, transparent 10%, transparent);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}





p {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,var(--side));
  text-align: center;
  z-index:10;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
#instruction {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2vmin;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: .78;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, hsl(198, 70%, 96%), hsl(198, 70%, 90%));
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!--
Scale: qXPdbw
Skew: PKJqJW
-->
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="origin">
  <div class="point"></div>
</div>
<p>transform-origin:<span id="transform-origin">50% 50%</span></p>

<span id="instruction">Press Anywhere to&nbsp;Change</span>
```